# How to programmatically add span id= to an HTML document

Tags: c#, javascript, html, d3.js

I am currently looking at an example D3 visualization that creates gauges on screen. The current body looks like this:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <span id="memoryGaugeContainer"></span>
    <span id="cpuGaugeContainer"></span>
    <span id="networkGaugeContainer"></span>
    <span id="testGaugeContainer"></span>
</body>
```

In my C# application, I need to call a javascript function that will create a

`<span id="id here"></span>`

line in the body. My C# code looks as so:

```
webView.ExecuteJavascript("createSpan(" + Convert.ToString(this.application.Document.Properties["column"]).Replace(" ", "_") + aggregation.SelectedItem.ToString() + flColumn.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace(" ", "_") + "GaugeContainer" + ")");
```

What would my Javascript function be? My current attempt at the "createSpan" function is this:

```
      function createSpan(id) {
      var spanTag = document.createElement("span");

      spanTag.id = id;

      document.body.appendChild(spanTag);
  }
```

The "executejavascript" function comes from Awesomium.

Am I doing this right?

Thanks

Comment: The createSpan should work. Instead of asking if you're doing right, why won't you tell us what is going wrong?

Comment: Right now, I am hosting HTML/Javascript to create a D3 Gauge onto a Windows Form inside Spotfire, using Spotfire's C# API. As of right now, I reformatted my program to execute Javascript functions to update the gauges on the fly (ie. every time I click the add button), rather than Regexing and changing the actual HTML file itself and then reloading it every time. Currently, my program does not display the gauges at all, and I thought that this may be one of the culprits as to why.

Comment: Well, I guess that you're creating the span element to frame the D3 Gauges. Perhaps the problem is the timing. Are you sure that the span exists before loading the D3 Gauges?

Comment: As soon as the user clicks the "Create Gauge" button, the HTML is loaded, which has an empty body, and no gauges created. Once the person clicks add, I run the createSpan function, which adds it to the HTML body. Then I run the createGauge function, which actually creates the gauges themselves.

Initially when the gauge button is clicked, an updateGauges function is set to be called every 100 milliseconds or so, before any gauges are even created. My reasoning is that once updateGauges sees a gauge that is created by the user clicking "add", it will automatically update it.

Comment: Are you running the d3 script on your page? If so you could just do `d3.select('body').append('span').attr('id', id);` as the body of your function.

Comment: Note you can also have it 'always present' in HTML, and use js to add `display: hidden` as necessary in CSS. I've found this to be sometimes easier/less troublesome in maintaining appearance.

Comment: I need to be able to add these span id's when the user clicks the add button, so they can't be stored ahead of time. The d3.select suggestion seems like it would do the same thing as above.

If worse comes to worse, I could revert back to Regexing down to the body initialize line, and then manually insert the span id lines and then reload the page every time it is added.

Comment: Update: Turns out the createSpan method isn't even being called, as I have inserted document.writes as well as a callback to a popup message in C#, and neither of them appear. I believe the formatting of my C# line is incorrect.

Comment: UPDATE: Turns out I'm silly and I was calling createSpan(abunchofcolumnnamesetc) instead of createSpan("abunchofcolumnnamesetc"). I feel silly for leaving out the quotations.